# My Java environment variables seem to be a complete mess how do I make a clean start without reinstalling?

Tags: environment-variables, java

I am trying to get `Janusgraph` working on **OpenSuse Leap 42.3** but I'm running into a multitude of problems.

My understanding is that `JanusGraph` invokes other Java dependencies, including `gremlin` & `cassandra`. I've tried from my account and from root but I gather from subsequent reading that running `janusgraph.sh` from root is either deprecated or impossible.

**I think that my Java environment variables are wrong and and running** `env` **reveals a bunch of variables relating to java and I don't know how or where they're generated or declared. I'd like to set these up in way that they're common across ALL accounts, which I think may be possible somehow, using** `/etc/environment`?

Here's the output from `env | grep J` + other manual extracts (all the following are run from my normal bash account, not root)

```
JRE_HOME=/usr/lib64/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk/jre/bin/java
JAVA_BINDIR=/usr/lib64/jvm/java/bin
JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/
JDK_HOME=/usr/lib64/jvm/java
JAVA_ROOT=/usr/lib64/jvm/java
CASSANDRA_HOME=/opt/apache-cassandra-3.11.3/bin/
PATH=/home/me/adb-fastboot/platform-tools:/home/me/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games:/home/me/bin:/usr/lib64/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk/bin/java:/usr/lib64/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk/jre/bin/java:/usr/bin/
```

but I think that contradicts:

```
alternatives --list java
/usr/lib64/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk/bin/java
```

I've also checked:

```
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 3.10.0) (build 1.8.0_191-b12 suse-30.1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
```

and to bottom out the actual location:

```
readlink -f /usr/bin/java
/usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0/jre/bin/java
```

and

```
whereis java
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/lib64/java /etc/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
```

Comment: me@machinename:/opt/janusgraph-0.2.2-hadoop2/bin> ./gremlin.sh                       
./gremlin.sh: line 133: /usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0/jre/bin//bin/java: No such file or directory, for example!
The point of the question is the paragraph in bold and I didn't think my environment was OK, but if it is I don't  know how I get the path issue  returned on trying to run gremlin.sh

Comment: Next time please include the errors, then. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Thanks Rui. If I'd felt that was possible I would have done, but I tried so many different approaches and got different results, some of which looked like they worked until I tried another step, only to find it hadn't. There is an exponential set of combinations and context explanations that would have made an answer impossible. As it was, Freddy took a holistic approach that sorted me out. Thanks for your input though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `PATH` variable is messed up and I don't know why you should need `JRE_HOME, JAVA_BINDIR, JDK_HOME` and `JAVA_ROOT`. Generally you will only need the `java` binary in your `PATH` and the `JAVA_HOME` variable. But maybe your setup requires some of these, so I would suggest you leave them until your environment works as desired.

Allow me to dissect your `PATH`, remove the entries with comments:

```
PATH=/home/me/adb-fastboot/platform-tools:
/home/me/bin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/bin:
/bin:
/usr/bin/X11:
/usr/games:
/home/me/bin: # remove, already defined above
/usr/lib64/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk/bin/java: # remove, java is already in /usr/bin
/usr/lib64/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk/jre/bin/java: # remove, java is already in /usr/bin
/usr/bin/ # remove, already defined above
```

Your new PATH is:

```
PATH=/home/me/adb-fastboot/platform-tools:/home/me/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games
```

JAVA_HOME/JRE_HOME should be:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib64/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk
JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME/jre
```

**Edit:** Your variables are probably exported in your ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile. Make the changes where you find them (with `export` before the variable name).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try out your suggestion and report back. Incidentally, in OpenSuse, I've found a script /etc/profile.d/alljava.sh  which seems to make/adjust some Java environment variables. (export JAVA_BINDIR = $JPATH/bin, export JAVA_ROOT=$JPATH,  export JAVA_HOME=$JPATH, unset JDK_HOME, unset SDK_HOME and more (keeping this shortish). Is this an area to avoid or keep in mind?

Comment: Yes, this looks like the place, but I can't tell you where "alljava.sh" comes from (OpenSuse?) and why the installation is broke. I prefer to add the variables to my ~/.bashrc, but that's just my preference. From what it looks like, set JAVA_ROOT to the same value as JAVA_HOME (`export JAVA_ROOT=$JAVA_HOME`) and `export JAVA_BINDIR=$JAVA_HOME/bin`

Comment: Yes, judging from the script header, it's an OpenSuse script to normalise all the main Java environment variables. I can paste it in, if it's useful to anyone?  I'm going to follow your advice and rationalise my bash `.profile ` for my account but it would still be useful to understand how to set up the whole system, so it's the same for all users, including root (I guess)

Comment: I cleaned out all my manually added Java environment variables and additions to PATH, in .profile and rebooted - I would have logged out/in but I wasn't sure whether the alljava.sh script was pre or post login, so it seemed easier just to reboot (it's my desktop not a publicly available server). Thanks for the pointers :)

Comment: Cool. Now you can start to eliminate all variables you don't really need. Or maybe tomorrow... :)